# (Jade/Pug) Apply a mixin on a parent block

Tags: pug

Suppose I have a parent template and a child template:

**base.jade:**

```
block content
 p this is the default text
```

**child.jade:**

```
extend base

block content
 p this is child text
```

Is it possible to capture the value of `block content` and apply a mixin that can affect all the child templates?

For example, I want to capitalize the content of `block content`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't forget that capitalization can be done via CSS too